# How to add space in many file names

Tags: powershell, insert, spaces

I was trying to remove all the underscores, spaces and square brackets from many animation files name, which made a big mess.

I used the code below to replace/remove the characters with what I want.

Replace

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*One Piece_*" -Recurse |
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'One Piece_','One Piece '}
```

Or (to delete space)

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "* *" -Recurse |
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ' ',''}
```

Now all the file names look like this:

`One Piece 031EEE7A115` → should be `One Piece 031 EEE7A115`
`One Piece 032FFB90605` → should be `One Piece 032 FFB90605`
etc.

Is there a way to insert space to all the files after the episode number?

Comment: Here's a great idea: try your code on a test set of files first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Make a regular expression that matches the substring from the beginning of the name up to three consecutive digits, and replace that with itself and a space:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*One Piece_*' -Recurse |
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^(.*?\d{3})', '$1 '}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code    '^(.*?\d{3})', '$1 '

Comment: @Zezo It means match everything up until the first 3 numbers encountered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: The ^ means to start matching at the beginning of the string.  Also [see this program](http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/108/) which allows for file renaming with preview.